# Split a vector using specific elements as delimiters

Tags: r, vector

For example in the following vector I want to use the zero elements as delimiters

```
x <- c(12, 1, 2, 15, 18, 0, 15, 13, 14, 9, 1, 0, 22, 9, 14, 3, 9, 20)
```

and get (maybe in a list) the vectors

```
c(12, 1, 2, 15, 18)
c(15, 13, 14, 9, 1)
c(22, 9, 14, 3, 9, 20)
```

How would you do that in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
splt <- cumsum(x == 0)
splt[x == 0] <- NA
split(x, splt)
# $`0`
# [1] 12  1  2 15 18

# $`1`
# [1] 15 13 14  9  1

# $`2`
# [1] 22  9 14  3  9 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this,

```
x <- c(12, 1, 2, 15, 18, 0, 15, 13, 14, 9, 1, 0, 22, 9, 14, 3, 9, 20)
lapply(strsplit(paste(x, collapse = ";"), "^0;|;0$|;0;"), function(y) {strsplit(y, ";")})[[1]]
# [[1]]
# [1] "12" "1"  "2"  "15" "18"

# [[2]]
# [1] "15" "13" "14" "9"  "1" 

# [[3]]
# [1] "22" "9"  "14" "3"  "9"  "20"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `rleid` from `library(data.table)` to create the grouping variable and then `split` the values of 'x' that are not 0 (`x[!!x]`) with the grouping variable.

```
library(data.table)
split(x[!!x], rleid(!x)[!!x])
```

Comment: This may well solve the problem, but please also provide an explanation. Many new users come to SO and explanation with your code helps them to learn how to adapt the code to solve their problem.

Comment: @JenB Or new users load the `data.table` and read `?rleid`, `?"!"`, `?split`. It is also a good way to learn.

Comment: I wasn't 'targeting' anything and I didn't downvote. Your post automatically went to the low quality review queue because it was code only. I did my standard comment for code only answers in that review queue (I wasn't presented with the other answers) even though you are a high rep user, because I didn't think it was fair to make such a comment only on low rep users. And now the answer is much better.

Comment: And I upvoted this interesting solution. And my answer can also be considered as "code only".